# Maximum of modulus of a series involving polynomials

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k $ be a polynomial of degree $n$ having no zeros in $|z|<1.$ Then what is the best value for  'M' in 
$$\frac{1+|a_0|}{n|a_0|}\left|\sum_{k=1}^nP(zw_k)\frac{w_k}{(w_k-1)^2}\right|\leq M$$ on $|z|=1$ where $w_k, 1\leq k\leq n$ are the roots of $z^n+|a_0|=0$

Comment: Can you tell us something about the context and what you have done so far?

Comment: The motivation is $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{w_k}{(w_k-1)^2}=\frac{-n|a_0|}{(1+|a_0|)^2}. $$

Comment: @user159888 If so, shouldn't it be $(1+|a_0|)^2$ rather than just $1+|a_0|$ in your question ?